# .NET apps not starting in windows 10

Tags: .net, sql-server, visual-studio-2012, windows-10, procmon

Ok, this is really a weird scenario.
I have installed MSSQL Server 2012 and Visual Studio 2012 in windows 10, fresh installation.
Everything was going fine but, suddenly, after a restart, and windows 10 updates, both of them stopped working.
I didn't lost time and just factory reset the PC to start over.
same scenario. I have managed to view whats going on with  procmon.exe and getting a strange "device data error" with clr.dll and mscorrc.dll.
Then I realized that this is happening with all apps requesting those dlls.
My guess is that something in the updates broke functionality but this seems to me a specific problem.
the only message I receive from apps is the common "App stopped working" and nothing else.
This is happening with all apps relative to .net but I can't do anything to fix/uninstall .net since it comes as a windows feature.
Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue.  You have to go into Services and start SQL Server manually.

[SQL Server not working after upgrading windows8.1 to windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31737231/sql-server-not-working-after-upgrading-windows8-1-to-windows-10)

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/77659/sql-server-not-starting-at-windows-startup-but-starts-manually

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this is not the case. I can tell because Viual studio is failing to start too. Even windows update Fails with this error code  0x80070643, which correspond to this article https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/976982 but I think this does not apply to windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is not that weird:
I reset the PC and let the windows update install the corresponding KBs, after that I was able to reproduce the issue.
Then I can confirm that it is related to an update which I uninstalled from settings->update and security->advanced options->update history->uninstall updates. I removed everything after the fresh windows install.
For some reason this update brakes something about .net functionality but after removing that, everything goes back to normal.
In addition I disabled windows service related to windows update.